# JQuery each getting value of multiple table data in a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Hi there I have this table which has multiple rows. **I want to know how to get certain data in each row of this table.** In this table I needed to get the student number data and it's accompanying grade.

```
<tbody>
   <?php foreach ($class_list_view as $student) { ?>
   <tr>
      <td class="studentnumber"><?= $student->studentnumber ?></td>
      <td><?= $student->lastname ?></td>
      <td><?= $student->firstname ?></td>
      <td><?= $student->middlename ?></td>
      <td><?= $student->level ?></td>
      <td><?= $student->year ?></td>
      <td>
         <select class="custom-select grade" style="height: 20px;">
            <option selected value="">Select Grade</option>
            <option value="passed">Passed</option>
            <option value="failed">Failed</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

What I have tried is using the `each` loop in jquery but I don't know how get similar/inline selectors with it.

```
 $("table tbody tr td.studentnumber").each(function (index) {
        studentnum_array.push( {"studentnumber": $(this).text(), "grade": $('table tbody tr td select.grade').val() } );
    });

     console.log( studentnum_array );
```

But in the `grade` index it only takes the first one. It should take in the value of the select in each row similar to the td `studentnumber`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through the rows instead of the cells...

```
var studentnum_array = [];

$("table tbody tr").each(function(index) {
    studentnum_array.push({ 
        "studentnumber": $(this).find('td.studentnumber').text(),
        "grade": $(this).find('select.grade').val()
    });
});

console.log(studentnum_array);
```

If you want to loop through the cells, you have to find the `select` in relation to the corresponding `studentnumber` cell...

```
var studentnum_array = [];

$("table tbody td.studentnumber").each(function(index) {
    studentnum_array.push({ 
        "studentnumber": $(this).text(),
        "grade": $(this).closest('tr').find('select.grade').val()
    });
});

console.log(studentnum_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already looping through each `td` then you need to find it's enclosing `tr` then find `select`.

```
 $("table tbody tr td.studentnumber").each(function (index) {
            var grade = $(this).closest('tr').find('select.grade').val();
            studentnum_array.push( {"studentnumber": $(this).text(), "grade": grade } );
        });

         console.log( studentnum_array );
```