# Inserting multiple rows from HTML table into database

Tags: php, mysql

I think my issue is with retrieving the id in the hidden field

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo "<tr><td><form action='workshopreq.php' method='POST'> <td=width='5%'><input type='checkbox' name='foo' value='bar1'/>  </td>"."<td>". $row["wID"]. "</td><td>" . $row["wName"]. "</td><td width='10%'>" . $row["services" ]. "</td><td>" . $row["other"]. "</td><td width='5%'>" . $row["area"]."</td>";

    echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='status' value='".$row["wID"]."'><input type='submit' name='conf' value='confirm'></td><td><input type='submit' name='decline' value='decline'></td></form></tr>";


}  


if(isset($_POST['conf'])){

        $sql1= "INSERT INTO acceptedWS(wName, wEmail, wPass, services, other, Workshop, area, starthr, endhr,clock1,clock2)
       SELECT  wName, wEmail, wPass, services, other, Workshop, area, starthr, endhr,clock1,clock2 FROM Workshop where Workshop.wID='".$row["wID"]."'";
        $res= mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

       }

if(isset($_POST['decline'])){

//delete from database

}


 echo "</table>"; }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: The HTML table was retrieved from another table in the database so it's not users inputting the data

Comment: That's an assumption that's not safe to make. Perhaps that's true *right now*, but what if that's not the case tomorrow? That's how [huge mistakes](http://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/) happen. Even then, just because something wasn't user generated doesn't mean it won't cause escaping problems. Always, **always** properly escape your data. Prepared statements with placeholder values do this automatically, reliably, and in a way that makes it absolutely clear that everything is done correctly.

Comment: What errors are you getting, please add them to your post so we can help you.

Comment: @rpm192 I'm not getting any errors but the rows are not getting inserted into the database

Comment: @Amna Please add these lines to your script, if it results in an error, please post it here. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: this might help you. Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725579/jquery-each-getting-value-of-multiple-table-data-in-a-table-row

Comment: This link may helps you [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725579/jquery-each-getting-value-of-multiple-table-data-in-a-table-row)